# Why is my woff that’s declared in my JSS stylesheet with @font-face not loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jss

Why isn’t my @font-face rule loading the woff? My `createStyleSheet()`:

Setup outside of my React component:

```
// ./jss.css
import jss from 'jss';
import vendorPrefixer from 'jss-vendor-prefixer';


/**
 * Reformat classNames
 * mechanism and format the classes as we see fit.
 *
 * @method createGenerateId
 * @return {String}         Formatted class name
 */
const createGenerateId = () => (rule) => {
    return rule.key.toString().replace(/\./, '_DOT_');
};


export default jss
    .use(vendorPrefixer())
    .setup({ createGenerateId });
```

Then inside:

```
import jss from './jss';
```

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.sheet = jss.createStyleSheet({
            '@font-face': {
                fontFamily: 'Whitney-BlackItal-ProGkCy-TDA',
                src: 'url(/fonts/woff/Whitney-BlackItal-ProGkCy-TD.woff)',
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                fontStyle: 'normal'
            }
        }).attach();
    }
```

The URL for the woff is good. If I hit that URL the browser downloads the .woff file. When I inspect the `this.sheet` instance I see the rule there.

My CSS class is formatted correctly:

```css
.font__Whitney--423 {
    font-family: Whitney-BlackItal-ProGkCy-TDB, Whitney-BlackItal-ProGkCy-TDA, Fallback, Courier;
    font-weight: "normal";
}
```

Nothing I’ve tried will actually load the woff file and display the styled text on screen.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the sheet itself connect properly - does other theme information get across? Does the path to the file match? Should it be relative – `url(./---` ? You could also try adding the format declaration to the url, like this: `src: "url(/fonts/woff/Whitney-BlackItal-ProGkCy-TD.woff) format('woff')",`.

Comment: Dear @BrandonDurham, Do you find a way to solve it?